# Listing number of rows by group

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database with members joining and I am trying to display the number of members from each country.

Here is the code I'm using to show the country flags:

```
    <?
       foreach( $sorters as $sortvalue )
      if( $sortvalue == '' )
         echo '<li> <a href="' . $list_url . $connector . $sortfield .
            '=none">None given</a> </li>';
      else
         echo '<a href="' . $list_url . $connector . $sortfield .
            '=' . $sortvalue . '"><img src="' . $flags . str_replace(' ', '_', $sortvalue) . '.gif" title="' . $sortvalue . '" alt="' . $sortvalue . '"></a> ' . $countrynum . ' fans<br>';
}
?>
```

I have really looked for the answer, and keep seeing the same type of code, but I haven't been able to get it to work for me.

I've tried this:

```
$countrynum = SELECT COUNT(name) FROM $table WHERE country = $sortvalue;
```

which I inserted after the foreach statement. This (and every other iteration of this I've tried gives me Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'COUNT' (T_STRING) in...

The closest I've come to solving this is by using this code (though, I shouldn't have to reconnect to the db should i?):

```
<?
   foreach( $sorters as $sortvalue )
      if( $sortvalue == '' )
         echo '<li> <a href="' . $list_url . $connector . $sortfield .
            '=none">None given</a> </li>';
      else
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
      foreach($dbh->query('SELECT country, COUNT(*) FROM $table GROUP BY country') as $row) {
         echo '<a href="' . $list_url . $connector . $sortfield .
            '=' . $sortvalue . '"><img src="' . $flags . str_replace(' ', '_', $sortvalue) . '.gif" title="' . $sortvalue . '" alt="' . $sortvalue . '"></a> ' . $row['COUNT(*)'] . ' fans<br>';
}
?>
```

This gave me the correct row (member) count, but the same single flag was displayed beside each number instead of the corresponding flag with number of members.

I'm sure this is probably super simple for lots of you, but I'm a newbie who's really trying to learn coding and so far that mostly means cutting, pasting and LOTS of trial and error. 
Any assistance (and learning resource suggestions) would be very much appreciated. :)

Comment: what is $sorters and $sortvalue?

Answer (score 0):

Since the flag image source is depending on`$sorters` and `$sortvalue`, it will be same for all country. Look at the loops. For each `$sorters as $sortvalue`, the link will be multiple countries but the `img` source will be same for all.

Comment: So how do I show each country flag with members and their corresponding number of members? What other information can I show to  help?

Comment: I only seem to be able to get either the correct flags to show with no numbers, or the correct numbers but with only a single flag showing for each entry. How do I get them both to show?